# How can i do 2 alignment in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So container in the middle can stretch i want left container alignment bottom how can i do ?

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(),
      Container(),
      Container()
    ],
  );
```

Comment: do you want all the containers to be aligned bottom left?

Comment: nope just left container inside have icon

Comment: did you try using the Align widget? also if you have an example of what you try to achieve that would be great

Comment: i have tried but not working

Comment: do you have a sketch or example that shows what you want to achieve?

Comment: please provide a clear view what do you want to achieve. It would be great then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dartpad.dev/471a8ad5bbccf642275873ec4c36b403

```
return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: item(Colors.blue, 'the middle is in the center')),
        Expanded(child: item(Colors.red, 'the middle \n is expanded ')),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: item(Colors.blue, 'the left container is \n alignment bottom'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: This is true but not working for me i dont understand